# How do I read data on Twilio Sync Stream

Tags: raspberry-pi, twilio, esp8266

I have successfully managed to pipe incoming texts (to my Twilio number) to a Twilio Sync Stream.

I have set up an IoT device where I want to retrieve that data.

How can I subscribe to the Stream to listen to new messages?

Alternatively, I can pipe the texts to a Twilio Sync List instead. But is it then possible to subscribe to the List in a similar manner? Basically, I'd like to receive this data as a push, instead of a pull - e.g. I'd like to avoid doing a REST request to the List URL every second.

Comment: I am not sure what the best way to do this is, but I have asked the Sync team at Twilio and will get back to you with their suggestions.

Comment: Sync JS sdk if your IoT device is powerful enough.

Sync JS SDK plus an mqtt gateway on the same RPi if the IoT device is not powerful enough.